# Paytab Payment gateway not working

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I have to integrate **[paytabs](https://www.paytabs.com/)** payment gateway. After integrating their sdk module, the application not builds & app gets an error.  My app gradle has below dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.4'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile project(':PayTabs_SDK_SRC')
}
```

The Error looks like:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: okhttp3/Address.class

**Update:**
If i remove below two dependency i don't get any error. But must have to use this 
**retrofit** dependence. Any Idea?

> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
>    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

Comment: can you share zip downloading link
I am unable to find ZIP

Comment: Can you please share zip for android Sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, PayTabs SDK includes 
`com.squareup.okhttp3(version 3.5.0)` and com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0 uses `okhttp3(version 3.6.0)` which confused Gradle and generates a dexException(duplicate files exception).

To solve this problem you need to exclude one of `okhttp3` version. Replace these below lines in build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

With these lines of code:

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'){
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp3"
}
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'){
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp3"
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: an you share zip downloading link I am unable to find ZIP